# Exporting Corpus from TM in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm trying to export `Corpus` objects from R to static files. The corpora contain stemmed documents created by parsing existing preprocessed files in the file system. The author describes a method to do this in his 'Introduction to Text Mining in R' (pp. 2), suggesting

```
> writeCorpus(file)
```

but my attempts so far only yield the following:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.PlainTextDocument", x):
    no applicable method for 'as.PlainTextDocument' applied to an object of class "character"
```

My script is pretty simple so far, and I expect it's likely a simple oversight. Any advice is greatly appreciated: it seems like fringe issue.

```
# Turn off Java so it doesn't interfere with Weka interface
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)

# Load required text mining packages
require(tm)
require(rJava)
require(RWeka)
require(Snowball)

# Populate a vector with the number of subdirectories in preprocessed dir
preprocessed <- list.files(path="preprocessed_dir", include.dirs=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

# For each element in the vector
for(i in 1:length(preprocessed)) {
# Get the files in each subdirectory by appending a number to the absolute path
    files <- list.files(sprintf("preprocessed_dir/%.0f", i))
    # Create a Corpus object of all the files in the subdirectory
    corpora <- Corpus(VectorSource(files))
    # Stem the words in the Corpus object
    corpora <- tm_map(corpora, SnowballStemmer)
    # (Try to) write the object to the file system
    writeCorpus(corpora)
}
```

FWIW: Calling `class(corpora)` returns 
`[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus" "list"`
so the objects are apparently not of type `character`

Comment: actually it looks like `corpora` is a `Corpus` class object before stemming, and then it becomes a `character` type object after stemming (which can't be written with `writeCorpus`)

investigating ways to coerce it back to a `Corpus` object!

Comment: alright, i'm a n00b so I can't answer my own question, but here it is:
`tm` casts `Corpus` objects that have been called by `tm_map` as `character` objects`. they have to be coerced back to `Corpus` objects before you can write them to the file system by calling 
`> corpora <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpora))

Comment: What directory is the corpus written to?

Answer (score 0):

I am wordering why you want to export a corpus. If you want to show the texts to others, you can just use the orignal texts.

If you want to export it and reuse it with R, my suggestion is that you can use the function save() in order to save the the corpus into a .RData.

Then if you want to load it, just use the load() function.